# How to draw a rectangle moving in a circle around the center of the canvas?

Tags: java, animation

The code is meant to draw a rectangle, which moves in a circle around the center of the canvas one time. The code I currently have is

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Q3_Circular extends JComponent {

protected int degree = 0;
protected double xStart;
protected double yStart;
protected Timer timer;


public Q3_Circular() {
    timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerCallback()); //creates new times that refreshes every 100 ms, and called the TimerCallback class
    timer.start();
}

protected class TimerCallback implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (degree < (2 * Math.PI)){
            xStart = getWidth()/2 * Math.cos(degree+1);
            yStart = getHeight()/2 * Math.sin(degree+1);
            degree+= 1;
            repaint();
        }
        else {
            degree += 0;
            repaint();
        }

    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AnimatedSquare");
    Q3_Circular canvas = new Q3_Circular();
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    frame.setVisible(true);
}   

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    xStart = (double)(getWidth())/2.0 * Math.cos(degree);
    yStart = (double)(getHeight())/2.0 * Math.sin(degree);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(xStart,yStart, 25,25));
    repaint();
}
}
```

This code appears to draw the rectangle very quickly around the point (0,0). I'm not sure where the code is wrong.

Comment: You need to know that the `degree` argument in the `Math#cos` and `Math#sin` are assumed to be in *Radian* not Degrees. Also you should know that the outputs of `sin` and `cos` functions can be **Negative** for some inputs. So your `xStart` and `yStart` are calculated as negative numbers which are drawn outside of your frame afterward. Also when you calculate the `xStart` and `yStart` in the `paintComponent` method, you are ignoring your calculations in `actionPerformed` method. Ask any question if these hints didn't help.

Comment: BTW, although its doesn't answer your question, but probably it can simplify your code. In Graphics2D you can use Affine Transforms for rotation. They'll basically let you to get rid of trigonometric functions. Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. The only problem I'm still having is that it's circling around the point 0,0 when it should be circling around the point  (getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2).

Comment: AHA! I figured out why it wasn't starting in the center, I had forgotten to add the getWidth()/2 and getHeight()/2 xStart and yStart. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was confusing.  Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Animated Square]

When creating a Swing GUI, use the model / view / controller pattern.  Create a GUI model, and GUI view, and one or more controllers to modify the model and repaint the view.

Here are the changes I made to your code.

1. I created a DrawingRectangle class to hold the information about the drawing rectangle.  This class is a plain old Java object with getters and setters.  This class is the GUI model.
2. I moved everything out of the main method except for the call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  The invokeLater method puts the creation and use of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  Oracle and I insist that all Swing applications start on the Event Dispatch thread.
3. I create the drawing rectangle in the constructor of the Q3_Circular class.  Generally, you create the GUI model, then the GUI view.
4. I rearranged the JFrame code in the run method to be in the proper order.  I removed the setSize method and replaced it with the pack method.  We don't care how big the JFrame is.  We care how big the drawing panel is.
5. I created a drawing panel from a JPanel.  Here, we set the preferred size of the drawing panel.  We extend a JPanel so we can override the paintComponent method.
6. The paintComponent method does nothing but paint the drawing rectangle.  No calculations or anything but painting is done in the paintComponent method.  I added a call to the super paintComponent method to maintain the Swing paint chain and clear the drawing panel before I paint the drawing rectangle.  I draw the rectangle using the x and y coordinates as the center of the rectangle, rather than the upper left corner.  This is the one transformation I do in the drawing code.
7. I created a drawing animation from a Runnable.  You can use a Swing Timer if you want.  I find it easier to create my own animation code.  This is the GUI controller.  Here is where we do the calculations, update the model, and repaint the drawing panel.  In the repaint method, I use the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to do the painting on the Event Dispatch thread.  I do this because the animation thread is a separate thread.

Here's the code.  I put all the classes together so I could paste the code easier.  You should separate the classes into different files.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Q3_Circular implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Q3_Circular());
    }

    private static final int DRAWING_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int DRAWING_HEIGHT = DRAWING_WIDTH;

    private DrawingRectangle drawingRectangle;

    public Q3_Circular() {
        int center = DRAWING_WIDTH / 2;
        Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(center, center, 32D, 32D);
        drawingRectangle = new DrawingRectangle(Color.RED, rectangle);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animated Square");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(DRAWING_WIDTH,
                DRAWING_HEIGHT, drawingRectangle);
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(new DrawingAnimation(drawingPanel, drawingRectangle))
                .start();
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8226587438110549806L;

        private DrawingRectangle drawingRectangle;

        public DrawingPanel(int width, int height,
                DrawingRectangle drawingRectangle) {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            this.drawingRectangle = drawingRectangle;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(drawingRectangle.getColor());

            Rectangle2D rectangle = drawingRectangle.getRectangle();
            int x = (int) Math.round(rectangle.getX());
            int y = (int) Math.round(rectangle.getY());
            int width = (int) Math.round(rectangle.getWidth());
            int height = (int) Math.round(rectangle.getHeight());
            g.fillRect(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);
        }

    }

    public class DrawingAnimation implements Runnable {

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        private DrawingRectangle drawingRectangle;

        public DrawingAnimation(DrawingPanel drawingPanel,
                DrawingRectangle drawingRectangle) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
            this.drawingRectangle = drawingRectangle;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int xCenter = drawingPanel.getWidth() / 2;
            int yCenter = drawingPanel.getHeight() / 2;
            double radius = drawingPanel.getWidth() / 3;

            for (int degree = 0; degree < 360; degree++) {
                double radians = Math.toRadians((double) degree);
                double x = radius * Math.cos(radians) + xCenter;
                double y = radius * Math.sin(radians) + yCenter;
                drawingRectangle.setRectangleOrigin(x, y);
                repaint();
                sleep(100L);
            }
        }

        private void sleep(long interval) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(interval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        private void repaint() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    drawingPanel.repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class DrawingRectangle {

        private final Color color;

        private Rectangle2D rectangle;

        public DrawingRectangle(Color color, Rectangle2D rectangle) {
            this.color = color;
            this.rectangle = rectangle;
        }

        public void setRectangleOrigin(double x, double y) {
            rectangle
                    .setRect(x, y, rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public Rectangle2D getRectangle() {
            return rectangle;
        }

    }

}
```